# Dual monitor stopped working after upgrade/dist-upgrade

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display

How do i fix the dual monitor set up with after an upgrade?

I am on

```
 $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

with the graphics card

```
 $ sudo lspci|grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [NVS 300] (rev a2)
```

[link](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product-nvs-300-us.html)

After I did an upgrade my dual monitor stopped working. I installed the following drivers but still no luck

```
$ nvidia-smi 

+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 340.107    Driver Version: 340.107        |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----
```

I should mention that I use this horrible adapter [horrible adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUfCD.jpg)

and my xrandr output is

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 8192 x 8192
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
   1680x1050     59.88*+  59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I rebooted the system several times oder the dist-upgrade and after installing the Nvidia drivers 
How can use the dual monitor setup again? what went wrong during the update?

**Update**
I am always surprised how Ubuntu works. I did not touch anything and suddenly after a reboot the dual monitor setup works again. I am amazed and shocked how Ubuntu works. my new xrandr output

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3360 x 1050, maximum 8192 x 8192
DP-0 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
   1680x1050     59.88*+  59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
DP-3 connected 1680x1050+1680+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
   1680x1050     59.88*+  59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Since you edited and mentioned that after a reboot the setup works again, can you post the new `xrand` output?

Comment: "After I did an upgrade my dual monitor stopped working." -> Can you be more specific about the steps? E.g. use tool X to perform upgrade of type Y, then immediately/after one reboot/after n reboots only monitor N showed an output. Some upgrades require a reboot to use a newer kernel, some drivers need tight integration with kernel (performed by a tool named DKMS). Did you use nvidia driver before the upgrade? Was everything fixed on the first reboot after the driver installation? Some proprietary driver introduce quirks in an otherwise smooth system.

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon X = `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`  ; Y =16.04 to 18.4  ; n > 4 , after upgrade/install of driver ; N consider xrandr output. Driver was not fixed after several reboots. I assume after reboot 8 to 15 on day 4 after upgrade  the problem was fixed

Comment: Thanks. Can you post the new `xrandr` output? There's no spontaneous persistent state change in Xorg. If Xorg behaves differently, something must have changed elsewhere. Perhaps the other monitor had some glitch inside that made it silent to DDC channel? Or even a bug in the nvidia proprietary part (driver, in-board firmware, hardware)?